# How to select the inputs (a,b) which minimize the output of the function f(a,b)?

Tags: r, function, input, output, minimization

I have a function `logit.aic(x,y)` that provides an output, given two inputs `x` and `y`.

**Restrictions:**
Both the inputs could be any positive non-integer value between *0* and *100*. Also, it should be `x < y`.

**Example:** `logit.aic(20,80)` returns the value *41.38729*.

**Problem:** I need to find the pair of inputs which minimizes the output of my function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it takes only single values. The problem is the desired input is not an integer, so I need some way to minimize automatically.